# How do I specify the range for the ed function in a Bourne Script?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am currently trying to code a function that fixes the spelling of a specific word in a Bash Script. What I have so far is:

```
        ed -s $argument <<END
        s/Old word/New word/g
        w $argument
        q 
END
```

However this obviously just fixes the last line of the file that I am feeding it. My question is how do I change it from END so that it goes through the entire file instead of just the last line?

Comment: Consider `sed -i 's/Old word/New word/g' "$argument"` where the `-i` option allows `sed` to edit-in-place.

Answer (score 1):

The range is specified before the command. In your case, you can use `,` to apply it to the whole file instead of the current line:

```
ed -s "$argument" <<END
        ,s/Old word/New word/g
        w
        q 
END
```

(The word `END` is an arbitrary here-document delimiter and unrelated to which lines are modified)

Comment: What version of ed uses % for the entire file instead of a comma?

Comment: Works in GNU ed but I can't find it documented ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯